# Is there any way to Not catching data by chrome browser?

Tags: jquery

In ( web hosting control panel ) file manager I changed my  code but in chrome and Firefox browser show my last code and new code doesn't show . 
I delete all codes but the browser work correctly .
I delete all catch data in chrome browser history but it work correctly and show my last code .
How can delete catch data ?
I do that with Opera browser it work OK and when i change my code in  file manager it changing . 
my problem with chrome and Firefox browser.
what can i do ?

```
// add this new code but in chrome and Firefox doesn't work 

 alert("test");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Press `F12` to open developer tools, select `Disable Cache` in the `Network` tab and reload the page, without closing the developer tools.

Comment: I'm beginner in jquery and php code . Do you know a php or jquery code for browsers that browsers don't Cache data and every time load fresh code ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a quick solution, try hitting `Ctrl+F5`
You can also try to disable the cache from the `Developer tools console -> Network tab` in Chrome

If you need that every time you update your script, it should load it fresh and not from cache ass s timestamp in the script URL like

```
my-script-location/script.js?10220103
```